# Definite integral including the ratio and power functions of a single variable

Tags: calculus, integration, exponentiation

I find trouble in calculating the following integral:

$$
\int_0^R \frac{m\cdot x}{m+s\cdot x^a} \,dx
$$

Mathematica does not provide an output for this function, however, there seems to be an output in the online http://integrals.wolfram.com/ tool for an upper limit to infinity.
The result given in this tool is as follows:
[online integration](http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=m%2ax/%28m%2bs%2ax%5Ea%29&random=false)

Any suggestions on the computation of this integral?
Perhaps any suggestions for approximating the integral under specific assumptions for the values of m, s,  a or R..

Comment: If $a$ is an integer, you should be able to do it by using partial fractions.

Comment: Since you're interested in an approximation, what are the relative sizes of $m,s,a,R$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am thinking that since the indefinite integral of this function equals to

$$
F(x)=\int \frac{m\cdot x}{m+s\cdot x^a} \,dx=x^2*\,_2F_1[1, 2/a, 1 + 2/a, -sx^a/m]/2
$$

Then, by taking F(R)-F(0) we get the result of the definite integral. Any remarks?

Result:
$$
\int_0^R \frac{m\cdot x}{m+s\cdot x^a} \,dx=F(R)-F(0)=R^2*\,_2F_1[1, 2/a, 1 + 2/a, -sR^a/m]/2
$$

Comment: Once you have the indefinite integral, the next step is fine.